# How to center and insert image and text in last column

Tags: tables, center

I want to create a table like the one below:

[image]

Thats how far i already got:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{| m{3,2cm} |m{3,4cm} | m{3,8cm}| m{3,8cm}|}
    \hline \hline 

    & {\textbf{Header1}} &   {\textbf{Header2}} &  {\textbf{Header3}} \\ [2ex] \hline \hline 
  {\textbf{Text}} & \centering Text1
\begin{minipage} {0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=3.2cm, height= 3cm]{image1} 

    \end{minipage} 
 &  \centering Text2
\begin{minipage} {0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=3.4cm, height= 3.1cm]{image2} 

    \end{minipage}
 &
Text3
  

    \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{text}\label{.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

When I try to center Header 3 with \centering it throws an error. Exactly the same when I try to insert image 3. I just dont know why?

Comment: end the row with `\tabularnewline` not `\\ `

Comment: I tried and it worked but the alignment of image 3 and text 3 is on top while the others are on the bottom. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: impossible to say, try to fix your example so it is a complete example (you can use `example-image` as that is generally available) then people can see your issue and debug. If you have an old copy of `array` (older than 2018)  then there was a bug in `m` columns in the final column. so show version of array package you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would load the `array` package and use its `\newcolumntype` directive to create a centered version of the `m` column type. Observe that it's not necessary to encase the `\includegraphics` directives in `minipage` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}                 % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % centered version of 'm' col. type
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| C{3.2cm} | C{3.4cm} | C{3.8cm}| C{3.8cm}| }
  \cline{2-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} 
  & {\textbf{Header1}} & {\textbf{Header2}} & {\textbf{Header3}} \\[0.5ex] 
  \hline  
  \textbf{Text0} 
  & Text1\strut % '\strut' creates some vertical separation to the image below
  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height= 3.1cm]{image1} 
  & Text2\strut
  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height= 3.1cm]{image2} 
  & Text3\strut
  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height= 3.1cm]{image3} 
  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{text}\label{.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Happy new year! +1, however I would set `strut` so, that bottom of images will be separated from `\hline` below of it.

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks, and happy new year to you as well! I found an even easier solution to the issue of separating the bottom edges of the graphs from `\hline`: simply get rid of the `minipage` "wrappers". Getting rid of the minipage wrappers also helps position the "Text0" material better.

Answer (score 2):

With use of `\adjustimage{<settings>}{<image file name>}` defined in the `adjustbox` package you can simple set position of images as well their margins. In MWE below is assumed, that all images can have the same width (from your code fragment follows that difference between them are very small). This assumption make table code shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\adjustboxset{width=\dimexpr\linewidth, height=32mm,
              valign=c, margin=0pt 4pt 0pt 2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\bfseries} l |*{3}{C|} }
    \hline \hline
        & \thead{Header 1}  & \thead{Header 2}  & \thead{Header 3}      \\ 
    \hline \hline
        &  Text 1           &   Text 2          &   Text 3              \\
Text    & \adjustimage{}{image1}
                            &  \adjustimage{}{image2}
                                                & \adjustimage{}{image3} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\caption{text}
\label{tab:images}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Considering @Mico comment, the width images can be changed by inserting `\height` and `width` in `adjustbox`. In this case table at `article` document class become wider than it standard text width. Consequently is advisable to change page layout with use of the `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox} % it also load grahicx package

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\adjustboxset{valign=c, margin=0pt 4pt 0pt 2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\bfseries\raggedright} X |*{3}{c|} }
    \hline \hline
        & \thead{Header 1}  & \thead{Header 2}  & \thead{Header 3}  \\ 
    \hline \hline
        &  Text 1   &   Text 2  &   Text 3                          \\
Text    & \adjustimage{width=34mm,height=16mm}{image1}
                    &  \adjustimage{width=38mm,height=16mm}{image2}
                                & \adjustimage{width=38mm,height=16mm}{image3} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\caption{text}
\label{tab:images}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You may want to point out explicitly, though, that you imposed equal widths on the three data columns. Just in case the OP has reasons for making the "1" column less wide than columns "2" and "3"...

Comment: You are right.  I see this, but since differences between width is very small and the size of text width as well document class are  is unknown, for sake of simple solution I decide to prescribe equal width to images. However, this can be simply corrected. I will write an addendum asap.